# Can't render react component with props from mobx

Tags: reactjs, render, mobx

I'm trying to render component inside another component in React.
I can't understand why optionwrapper doesn't renders when fetching is done.
It would be perfect if someone can explain why it doen't work

```js
const SearchResults = () => {
  useEffect( () => {
    GlobalStore.setOptions();
  }, []);
return(
    
      <div className={styles.column}>
        {
          GlobalStore.getOptions.result=='OK' &&
          
          <OptionWrapper options={ GlobalStore.options.data.body} />
        }
       
   </div>
)}
```

and in Store i have this

```js
import { observable, makeObservable, action, computed, toJS , configure  } from 'mobx';

configure({
  useProxies: "never"
})

class MainStore {
  options = new Object;

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      options: observable,
      setOptions: action,
      getOptions: computed,
    })
  }
  
  setOptions() {
    
    fetch(http)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.options = data
        console.log(this)
        
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
      
  }
  get getOptions() {
    return toJS(this.options);
  }
}

const GlobalStore = new MainStore;

export default GlobalStore;
```

and i have no idea why it doesn't work

Comment: Does it work if you use [observer](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html) on your component?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should wrap SearchResults component using observer

```
const SearchResults =observer(() => {
  useEffect( () => {
    GlobalStore.setOptions();
  }, []);
return(
    
      <div className={styles.column}>
        {
          GlobalStore.getOptions.result=='OK' &&
          
          <OptionWrapper options={ GlobalStore.options.data.body} />
        }
       
   </div>
)})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, InfoWindow } from "react-google-maps";
import MarkerWithLabel from "react-google-maps/lib/components/addons/MarkerWithLabel";
import styles from './MyMapComponent.module.css';
import GlobalStore from '../../../stores/MainStore';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

const MyMapComponent = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(observer((props) => {
  const icon = {
    url: " ",
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(0, 0)
  };
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);
  return(
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={11}
      defaultCenter={{lat: props.Markers.searchResults.results[0].coordinate.lat, lng: props.Markers.searchResults.results[0].coordinate.lon}}
    >
      {props.isMarkerShown && props.Markers &&
        props.Markers.searchResults.results.map((val, index)=>(
        <MarkerWithLabel
          position={{ lat: val.coordinate.lat, lng: val.coordinate.lon }}
          key={val.thumbnailUrl}
          labelAnchor={new google.maps.Point(0, 0)}
          icon = {icon}
          title={val.id.toString()}
          
          onClick={(e)=>{
            GlobalStore.setPropertySelected(e);
            setFlag(!flag);
            
          }}
          >
          <div className={GlobalStore.propertySelectedId == val.id ? styles.marker_label_selected : styles.marker_label}>
            {val.ratePlan.price.current}
          </div>
        </MarkerWithLabel>
          ))
      }
      {/* я пытался использовать переменную из mobx, но тогда не работает */}
      {flag &&
          <InfoWindow
            position={ {lat: GlobalStore.propertySelected.coordinate.lat, lng: GlobalStore.propertySelected.coordinate.lon} }
            onCloseClick={()=>setFlag(!flag)}
          >
            <div className='styles.rap'>
            <img src={GlobalStore.propertySelected.thumbnailUrl}/>
            <h6>{GlobalStore.propertySelected.ratePlan.price.current}</h6>
            <h5>{GlobalStore.propertySelected.address.streetAddress}</h5>
            <h6>Rating: {GlobalStore.propertySelected.guestReviews.rating}</h6>
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
        
      } 
    </GoogleMap>
  ) })
))

export default MyMapComponent ;
```

this is how I fix problem.
as You can see I use observer and it didn't help